# azcopy sync failing with "409 Public access is not permitted on this storage account." on private container

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a VM and the Vnet of the VM is added on the Storage account('allow access from selected network' setting).
I run `azcopy.exe sync` command from the VM and it works when the Blob container is public. When I make it private it fails with this error:

```
Code: PublicAccessNotPermitted
RESPONSE Status: 409 Public access is not permitted on this storage account.
```

So if public access is not allowed then sync will not work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS key worked but access key failed for private blob container. So changing to SAS key was my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was setting a SAS token with READ permissions (then all permissions at the object-level) and having no luck.

But creating a SAS token with read and list permissions at the container-level solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while creating azure infra with terraform.

I added :

```
  container_access_type = "private"
```

inside:

```
    resource "azurerm_storage_container" "cont1" {
     ...
     ...
     ...
    }
```

in the **main.tf** file.

Hope that can give some support to resolve on your context.